# passing multiple parameters to sql procedure as a single string variable

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, procedures

From front end(studio 2008) I am passing values to sql procedure as :

string a = "hello" + "098765" + "world" + "90.0909"

These are 4 different values that I've concatenated into a string a;

now i pass this **string a** to the sql procedure using c# sqlCommand object.

Now, how do I retrieve these 4 values in sql procedure as I've created the procedure as:

```
create procedure Proc_name (@concatenated_string varchar(100))
as
insert into table1 values(**how can i get those 4 values here**).
```

I used arrays but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not just have four parameters on the procedure?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to create a generic "insert" procedure to handle all of your inserts for a variety of different tables. If that's so - WHY?!?!? You gain nothing in terms of code quality (speed, readability), create significant security concerns, and in general make life difficult for everyone.

Comment: You have no delimiter in your string, it ends up as hello098765world90.0909 which is meaningless.  At least if you put a |, ¬ or , or anything in between then you'd have a chance to split it...

Comment: ok ck if i put comma as a delimiter then how to do with arrays (though people say not to use generic procedure but still i would like to know how to work with arrays)??????????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be to use four parameters on the procedure:

```
create procedure Proc_name (@param1 varchar(100), 
    @param2 varchar(100), 
    @param3 varchar(100), 
    @param4 varchar(100)) 
as 
insert into table1 values(@param1, @param2, @param3, @param4)
```

Then from your code (giving a c# example using ADO.NET)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Create the command and set its properties.
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand 
       ("Proc_name", connection); 

    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // Add the input parameters and set the properties.
    SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@Param1";
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter.Value = param1;

    SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@Param2";
    parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter.Value = param2;

    // Same for params 3 and 4...


    // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter4);


    // Open the connection and execute the reader.
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    reader.Close();
}
```

Comment: With EnterpriseLibrary this becomes **much** cleaner.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass an array into SQL Server to deal with "multirow" updates on one table, read this [famous article(s).](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

If you want a generic stored proc to update any table, then don't as per other comments

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 then you might want to look at sending your data through to your stored procedure as an XML parameter. [This link](http://www.smallworkarounds.net/2009/07/sending-list-of-complex-objects-to-sql.html) explains the process perfectly

Here's a sample section of how your code might look using .NET 3.5 and C#

**// sample object**

```
[Serializable]
internal class MyClass
{
    internal string Property1 { get; set; }
    internal string Property2 { get; set; }
    internal int Property3 { get; set; }
    internal string Property4 { get; set; }
}
```

**// sample serialization**

```
internal static string SerializeObject<T>(T objectGraph)   
{   
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   

    XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();   
    writerSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;   
    writerSettings.Indent = true;   

    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, writerSettings))   
    {   
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));   
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();   
        ns.Add(String.Empty, String.Empty);   
        xs.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectGraph, ns);   
    }   

    return sb.ToString();   
}
```

**// sample stored procedure**

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProc]   
    @myClassXML XML   
AS   
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] 
    (   
        P1,   
        P2,   
        P3,   
        P4   
    )    
    SELECT    
        Container.ContainerCol.value('Property1[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS P1,   
        Container.ContainerCol.value('Property2[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS P2,     
        Container.ContainerCol.value('Property3[1]', 'int') AS P3,     
        Container.ContainerCol.value('Property4[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS P4,     
    FROM @myClassXML.nodes('//MyClass') AS Container(ContainerCol)    
END
```

I am assuming that you've read the advice of other answers here and are not creating a generic "Insert Anything" stored procedure as this is one of the worst things that you could do.

Note: This code was written in Notepad++ and thus hasn't been tested.

Answer (score 1):

use several parameters instead of 1, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addUser]

    @idRole int,  
    @userName varchar(255),  
    @password varchar(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
    set nocount on

    insert into userTbl (  idRole , userName , password  )
     VALUES (  @idRole , @userName , @password  )

    return scope_identity();
    END

    GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate the 4 strings with a comma between and split it in the database back.

E.g.

```
declare @values as nvarchar(1000)
set @values = 'hello,098765,world,90.0909'
SELECT * FROM split(@values) 

----------------  SPLIT FUNCTION  --------------
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[split]
(
    @csv nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS 
@entries TABLE 
(
    entry nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @commaindex int
    SELECT @commaindex = CHARINDEX(',', @csv)

    IF @commaindex > 0 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @entries
        -- insert left side
        SELECT LTrim(RTrim(LEFT(@csv, @commaindex-1)))
        -- pass right side recursively
        UNION ALL
        SELECT entry
        FROM dbo.split(RIGHT(@csv, LEN(@csv) - @commaindex))        
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @entries
        SELECT LTrim(RTrim(@csv))

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really do just want to use one parameter, then maybe consider an XML parameter rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<T> updateSiteDetails<T>(int SiteId, int CategoryId, string[] values)
    {
        int temp = values.Count();
        int Counter = 0;
        List<T> SiteDetails = null;
        var parameterData = new string[temp];
        var para = new string[temp];
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
            Counter =Counter++;
            parameterData[Counter] = "@,value"+Counter;
            para[Counter] = string.Format(","+value);
        }
        //string ParameterDatas=string.Join(",",parameterData);
        string parameterValue = string.Join(",",para);
        using (SBDEntities db = new SBDEntities())
        {
            SiteDetails = db.Database.SqlQuery<T>("Sp_Update_Data @SiteId,@CategoryId" + string.Join(",", parameterData),string.Join(",",para)
                   //new Object[] { new SqlParameter("@SiteId", SiteId),
                  // new SqlParameter("@CategoryId",CategoryId)}
        ).ToList();
            }
            return SiteDetails;
        }
```

in case you are using stored procedure with Entity framework